# Microphone doesn't work for any program except for the control panel

Tags: windows-7, microphone

I'm using both a line in mic, and a built in microphone array with my laptop.

When I go to Control panel > Hardware and Sound > Manage audio devices, I see the bars go up and down in the recording tab, but no programs that I use can actually tell that I'm using a microphone.

Whats wrong?

How do I fix it?

Comment: do they work by themselves ? , is this a new problem ?

Comment: well the desktop mic, the line-in works great on my desktop.  I'm assuming they work because I can see the sound bars go up and down, just not for all programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go back to the manage audio devices window and double click on one of the microphones, go to the advanced tab and check both boxes if they are unchecked. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Why/how would this help?

Comment: If they are unchecked, it's possible Windows isn't letting the application(s) use the microphones.